# Confusion with a simple assembly code for AVR

Tags: avr, assembly

Im using ATmega328P with Atmel Studio.
I have a problem understanding the register manipulation in this code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB =  0b00000111;
    PORTB = 0b00000111;

    while (1)
    {           
        PORTB = 0b00000000;         
        PORTB = 0b00000111;     
    }
}
```

And here is its assembly:

```
     5: {
     6:     DDRB =  0b00000111;
00000040 87.e0                LDI R24,0x07      Load immediate 
00000041 84.b9                OUT 0x04,R24      Out to I/O location 
     7:     PORTB = 0b00000111;
00000042 85.b9                OUT 0x05,R24      Out to I/O location 
    12:         PORTB = 0b00000000;
00000043 15.b8                OUT 0x05,R1       Out to I/O location 
00000044 fd.cf                RJMP PC-0x0002        Relative jump
```

And here is the view of I/O registers for PORTB for the last execution:

[image]

**My question is:**

If we go step by step, here 00000111 is moved to R24 cpu register and it is moved DDRB register which is at the address 0x04:

```
        DDRB =  0b00000111;
00000040 87.e0                LDI R24,0x07      Load immediate 
00000041 84.b9                OUT 0x04,R24      Out to I/O location
```

Here the same bit pattern at R24 is applied to the register PORTB

```
     PORTB = 0b00000111;
00000042 85.b9                OUT 0x05,R24      Out to I/O location
```

But what is happeing in the last two lines here:

```
00000043 15.b8                OUT 0x05,R1       Out to I/O location 
00000044 fd.cf                RJMP PC-0x0002        Relative jump
```

First of all what is R1 which is not declared? And my code **has nothing to do with PINB register** but how come the PINB's PINB0, PINB1 and PINB2 becomes 1 here? Last two lines are:

Comment: It looks like (at a guess) it's relying on R1 being initialised to zero either in the startup code or by the processor reset. And it looks like the input ports shadow the value of the output ports - which makes sense, electrically.

Comment: @pjc50 What do you mean by "input ports shadow the value of the output ports"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First of all what is R1 which is not declared?

`r0` ... `r31` are the AVR's general purpose registers. `r1` is set to 0x00 by the start up code gcc implicitly generates and is then assumed by the compiler to contain 0x00 forever. Hence, wherever 0x00 is needed but a literal cannot be used, gcc simply uses `r1`. (Similarily, `r0` is reserved as temporary storage register and may be used for any purpose in any piece of code because gcc will never use it to store anything across a function call or an inline assembly section.)

See also https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Register_Layout.

> And my code has nothing to do with PINB register but how come the PINB's PINB0, PINB1 and PINB2 becomes 1 here?

`PINx` represents the value (high/low) as seen on the pin. When you output a value via PORTx, that value also is reflected in the PINx (delayed by 1 clock cycle, IIRC). That's also explicitly mentioned in the datasheets.

Comment: Interesting. Never saw this information in any tutorials. I dont know the reason to spend an extra clock cycle for this. Also I cant see the address of PINx which is 0X23 in the assembly code. (?)

Comment: The reason for the extra cycle is that it's not the PORTx register value that gets copied, but PINx always reads the pin's value. So when you output a value on a pin in one cycle it's not until the next cycle that the input logic detects the new value and puts it into the PINx register.

Comment: "I cant see the address of PINx which is 0X23 in the assembly code." - Why should you? Your program does not access that register.

Comment: ok you mean the compiler takes care of that "always read pin value" part?

Comment: No, the *hardware* always reads the pin value into PINx on every cycle.

Comment: PINx shows the actual state of the pin while PORTx shows the state of the output drivers. And it's actually not guaranteed that PINx will follow PORTx after one clock cycle, or even at all. If the pin is externally shorted to vcc or ground or has a very large capacitive load, the corresponding bit in PINx will either stay at zero or take many clock cycles to reflect the new state.

Comment: @user16307, you can generally see these in the datasheets or the avrdude header files.( as well as the studio window above).  Interesting how the optimiser has re-used R24 as a constant of the same value. Only seeing Port B is suggestive of an ATTiny rather than an ATMEGA328 ?